# How can override log template?

Tags: logging, joomla3.0

I want to write log my component when i save or publish one item.
How can i override log template in joomla 3?
The default output like this:

```
2013-06-03T04:41:53+00:00   INFO    -   Some text is here
```

I just want to remove datetime.
I'm using JLog class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add option for logger like this:

```
JLog::addLogger(array('text_file' => 'log_file.log',
                      'text_file_path' => JPATH_ROOT . '/logs',
                      "logger" => "formattedtext",
                      "text_entry_format" => '{PRIORITY}    {CATEGORY}  {MESSAGE}'));
```